# Convert array to object using array values for object key value pairs

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array:

```
const arr = [ 'name=Jon', 'weapon=sword', 'hair=shaggy' ]
```

And I want to convert it to an object like this:

```
const obj = { name: 'Jon', weapon: 'sword', hair: 'shaggy' }
```

I've tried splitting the array by the `=` to get the `key` and `value` and then mapping the new array and sending those values to an empty object but it doesn't get the right key

```
const split = arr.map( el => el.split('=') )
let obj = {};
split.map( el => {
  const key = el[0];
  const val = el[1];
  obj.key = val;
  }
)
```

`obj` returns as `{key: 'shaggy'}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**Object.fromEntries**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

```js
const arr = [ 'name=Jon', 'weapon=sword', 'hair=shaggy' ]

const obj = Object.fromEntries(arr.map(v => v.split('=')))

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 4):

Generally, to convert an array into an object, the most appropriate method to use is `.reduce`:

```js
const arr = [ 'name=Jon', 'weapon=sword', 'hair=shaggy' ];
const obj = arr.reduce((a, str) => {
  const [key, val] = str.split('=');
  a[key] = val;
  return a;
}, {});
console.log(obj);
```

You should only use `.map` when you need to create a new array by carrying out an operation on every item in the old array, which is not the case here.